# How do I combine missing data in one table with another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I have two tables. I need to join data from table A to table B. Both tables have the same field names and same set of data, except Table A has quite a few rows of data that table B does not have.

The common field between the two is called APN. How can I combine the missing data from table A to table B? I do not want to move over data already inside table B.

ArcGIS software*

Comment: Please... what format, what software ??? How to help without that info ?

Comment: ArcGIS software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the larger table to the smaller table via the common field, selecting Keep All Records. Sort the joined table to see which ones are in one but not the other, export those records. Then append the missing records to Table A

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I have been inside ArcGIS for too much time lately and it caused my brain to freeze and not be able to think this one through. Much appreciation.

Comment: Im glad to help!

Comment: I did the join - and it did not combine the missing records for comparison. Any idea what I am doing wrong? It is not including the extra records.

Comment: Try joining the other way around, the values that are not in the other table should appear as null records

Answer (score 0):

One can use @Maksim procedure, but avoid the use of appending after sorting and selection; Copy the selected data and paste to the data which is to be updated. The data to be copied is the extra missing data with Null values or fields. Remember to remove joins. The method works faster.